# System.out.println ("\"\"\\\\\"\"");

Tags: java

Why does this string print only ""\\""? Does the backslash do something to the string? Please explain the function of the backslash. All I know is that it is the escape character, but I don't understand why it does this to strings.

Comment: FYI the fact that you are using BlueJ is not actually relevant.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis Sorry. I thought it'd be useful info. I will edit it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash '\' can be used in a String to add characters that would otherwise be illegal (e.g. " and ') or have another meaning (e.g. t, b, n, r, f and \). for your particular example :

1. The first 2 backslashes are escaping the double quotes. So `\"\"` is printed as `""`
2. The next backslashes are escaping the backslashes that immediately follow so `\\\\` is printed as `\\`
3. The last 2 backslashes behave as the first 2 escaping the quotes so `\"\"` is printed as `""`

Comment: I would add for beginners: You have to use a backlash \ if you wan't to treat an special character as a String and it is the reason why it happens.

Comment: Agreed. Except '/' is a slash and '\' a backslash.

Comment: Of course. Totally agree. A silly mistake :S

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis Thanks for the link. I actually read it before I posted this question. But it does not tell what a backslash does to a string. Maybe I missed something though

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis Sorry. I meant the top part of the question where it said it was a duplicate. Marcus's answer is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The Backslash is the *escape character*, used to encode special things like `"` in your string (which you normally couldn't use, because they'd mark the end of a string). You should read up on "String literals" in the [official Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html) or the book you read to learn Java.